# How to query associations in Linq to Entity framework in .NET Ria Services

Tags: linq-to-entities, wcf-ria-services

I have just started with Linq and Linq to Entity Framewok. On top of that with the .NET Ria services. 
My problem is that I have 2 tables Folder and Item with a many to many relationsship using a third "connection" table FolderItem like this:
[image]
<sub>(source: [InsomniacGeek.com](https://InsomniacGeek.com/Downloads/Model1.png))</sub>
[image]

In the .NET RIA Service domain service, I want to create a method that returns all Items for a given FolderID.

In T-SQL , that would something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Item i
INNER JOIN FolderItem fi ON fi.ItemID = i.ID
WHERE fi.FolderID = 123
```

My Linq knowledge is limited, but I want to do something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Item> GetItems(int folderID)
{
  return this.Context.Items.Where(it => it.FolderItem.ID == folderID);
}
```

This is not the correct syntax, it gives this error:

> Cannot convert lambda expression to
>   type 'string' because it is not a
>   delegate type

What is the correct way of doing this (with associations) ?

Can I user the .Include("FolderItem") somehow?

Please, method syntax only.

PS.
Here's how it would look like using a Query Expression:

```
  public IQueryable<Item> GetItemsByFolderID(int folderID)
  {
    return from it in this.Context.Items
           from fi in it.FolderItem
           where fi.Folder.ID == folderID
           select it;
  }
```

The qeustion is, how would it look like using the Method Based Query Syntax?

Comment: What is wrong with your suggested GetItems (except that the "=" should be "==")? Have you tried it?

Comment: Craig, that was a typo. I've fixed it.

Comment: I presume the s. in the Query Expression is also a typo and should be c.? At any rate, I still see nothing terribly wrong with GetItems as you wrote it, but I'll give you a different option below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your GetItems looks fine to me. You could also do:

```
public IQueryable<Item> GetItems(int folderID)
{
    return this.Context.FolderItems
                       .Where(fi => fi.ID == folderID)
                       .Select(fi => fi.Items);
}
```

Both should return the same thing.

Comment: Great. Just what I wanted. Thanks. This way of attacking the data from its parent entity, I didn't think of.

Answer (score 2):

You can have the parent entity contain the child entities. There are 2 things you have to do to do this:

1) Update your domain query to include the folder items and items:

```
return from x in Context.FolderItems
                        .Include("FolderItem")
                        .Include("FolderItem.Item")
       where x.ID == folderID
       select x
```

2) Update the metadata file so that the RIA service knows to return the associations to the client:

```
[MetadataTypeAttribute(typeof(FolderMetadata))]
public partial class Folder
{
     internal sealed class FolderMetadata
     {
           ...
           [Include]
           public FolderItem FolderItem; 
     }
}
```